# Suppressing a line in a pgplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Good Afternoon, I would love to make the vertical line that outlines the area of the green trapezoid a dashed rather than a continuous line... Unfortunately, I'm really new to pfgplot, and I don't really now how to do this... Basically, it seems that LaTeX is "drawing twice" the dotted lines, so that they juxtapose a bit... I would also love to flip the yaxis label and put it on the top of the axis...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
compat=newest,
axis lines = left,
xlabel = {$\text{A\&D} / 100k$},
ylabel = {$gp$},
xmin = 0,
ymin = 0,
xmax = 60,
ymax = 730,
xtick={0,20},
ytick={40+20/3,160+20/3,560+20/3},
title = {Locals, Peak},
]
\addplot[
domain = 0:75,
samples = 190,
thick,
]
{560 + 20/3 - 20*x};
\draw [dotted] (0,160+20/3) -- (20,160+20/3) -- (20,0);
\draw [dotted] (0,40+20/3) -- (26, 40 + 20/3) -- (26,0);
\draw [pattern = north east lines, pattern color = green](0, 40 + 20/3) -- (0,560 + 20/3) -- (20, 160 + 2/3) -- (20, 40 + 2/3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your problem is that the pattern is obscuring the dotted lines.  You should draw it before rather than after.  You can place a node containing gp anywhere.  (rel axis cs: 0,1) will do.  Finally, \text is defined in amsmath, or use \textrm.

Comment: BTW, TikZ is drawing the lines precisely where you told it to.  If you don't want lines drawn, don't tell TikZ to draw them.